# android studio: Unable to recreate missing debug keystore

Tags: android, debugging, keystore

I've installed the android studio (0.4) on my ubuntu machine. Trying to run a "hello world" application I got the follwing error message:

> Execution failed for task ':myApp:validateDebugSigning'.
>   Unable to recreate missing debug keystore.

The ~/.android/ doesn't contain any keystore file.

Does anybody know how I can resolve that issue?

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable (if not, to `~/.android/` by default), Android Studio, Eclipse are based on this variable for debug.keystore and AVD configuration and files（PATH：`$ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/`）.

If set, you can move `~/.android/ to $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/`.

If debug.keystore does not exist, Android Studio will automatically create it, **please keep $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/.android/ writable**, or they can be created by keytool command。

I finished the above content with the aid of translation tools.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I do not understand the answer above, can someone explain me how to solve that issue ? I am also new to Android and I do not know what to do...

Thank you for your help

EDIT:

For information, I found how to solve this.

If like me, you have no debug.keystore in your `~/.android` folder and you receive the same message as above, you can solve this by changing the security permission of your folder. By giving it a read/write, Android studio was able to run the application correctly. Hope this could help someone...